# Facebook opengraph images from links

Tags: facebook

I understand that in Facebook the images posted from links must be at least 200 in each dimension. But what image does FB choose as an alternative when they are not?  Can I set a default image for my posts that come from links?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) specifiy an Open Graph image for every link anyway: https://ogp.me/

```
og:image
og:image:secure_url
og:image:width
og:image:height
```

I recommend using the width and height parameters too, or Facebook will not show the image when someone publishes the link for the first time.